# What am I missing for this reverse order?

Tags: java, reverse

This is what I have so far:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ReverseNumber {

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         int n, reverse = 0;

         System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         n = in.nextInt();

         while( n != 0 )
         {
             reverse = reverse * 10;
             reverse = reverse + n%10;
             n = n/10;
         }

         System.out.println(" in reverse order is "+reverse);
      }
   }
```

If the user input were to be 123, then what it prints out, the way it is now, is this:

Enter an integer:

in reverse order is 321

I need to know what to put in to get it to print 123 in front of 'in reverse order is 321' statement.

Comment: what is variable n in you code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are changing the value of the input, you need to store it in a different variable and change the Sys out statement to add the actual value, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int input, n, reverse = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = in.nextInt();
    input = n;
    while( n != 0 )
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + n%10;
        n = n/10;
    }

    System.out.println(input + " in reverse order is "+reverse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do it this way

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                int n, reverse = 0;
                System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                n = in.nextInt();
                int number = n;
                System.out.println(n);
                while( n != 0 )
                {
                    reverse = reverse * 10;
                    reverse = reverse + n%10;
                    n = n/10;
                }
                System.out.println(number+" in reverse order is "+reverse);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two different line if you want initialize multiple variables at the same time.

Since you are changing `n`, create a copy you can use.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     int n, reverse, initialNumber;
     n = reverse = initialNumber = 0;

     System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     n = in.nextInt();
     initialNumber = n;

     while( n != 0 )
     {
         reverse = reverse * 10;
         reverse = reverse + n%10;
         n = n/10;
     }

     System.out.println(initialNumber + " in reverse order is " + reverse);
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EhBs/0)